# Determine which protocol to use - EWS, WebDav, or OWA?

Tags: webdav, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-app

We're building a system to log in to a user's exchange account.
The biggest issue we're facing is determining the method in which to connect to a user's account - be it Exchange Web Services, Outlook Web Access, or WebDAV. How can we determine which is turned on, and which isn't?

Answer (score 0):

Different protocols will provide different levels of access. Also different versions of Exchange Servers only support certain protocols. In order to be able to log into a broad range of email accounts you may end up having to support multiple protocols.

**WebDAV** is widely supported in Exchange 2000/2003. Support for it was reduced in Exchange 2007 and then dropped in Exchange 2010.

**EWS** is not supported in the earlier versions of Exchange but is well supported in Exchange 2007/2010 and Exchange365

**IMAP** is supported by all versions of Exchange but you would only have reduced functionality via this protocol